# Getting A Django Template Syntax Error. How do I solve this?

Tags: python, html, django

I tried to extend the base.html file in index.html. But I keep getting the following error:
Invalid block tag on line 2: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <!-- {% block css_files %} {% endblock %} -->
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block title %} My Blog {% endblock %} {% block
content %} Hello {% endblock %}
```

I've made sure there are no gaps between any of the curly braces and %. Where could be the issue?

Comment: Try removing `{% extends 'base.html' %}` and if the error goes away, you should be looking in that file

Comment: Modify "My blog" to "My blog BB" and if it doesn't get rendered, the template is getting loaded from somewhere else!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a newline in the middle of a tag, start each block tag on a separate line

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}My Blog{% endblock %}

{% block content %}Hello{% endblock %}
```